# Is it possible to use immutable collections in this case?

Tags: f#, immutability, immutable-collections

I have translated a code from python to F# but I wished to use a more idiomatic syntax.
I think that there are two big obstacles

- poor performance (consider that `n` is very big)
- not powerful enough abstractions

The current (working) code I have is

```
let valuefolded =
    System.Collections.Generic.List(
        [0..( (n - (offset % input.Length) - 1) / input.Length)]
        |> List.fold
            (fun acc _ -> List.append acc input)
            (input
            |> List.skip (offset % input.Length)))
for repeat in [0..99] do  
    let mutable acc = 0
    for i in ([0..(n-1)] |> List.rev) do
        valuefolded.[i] <- Math.Abs(acc + valuefolded.[i]) % 10
        acc <- valuefolded.[i]
```

(fyi on my laptop with actual data it takes about a minute)

Now there are two mutable that I wish to make immutable, if it is possible and if it makes sense.

1. the `mutable acc` (this is done, see below)
2. the `System.Collections.Generic.List` wrapper

Comment: What benefits will you gain by making the collection(s) immutable?

Comment: Well, it would have to "make sense" for *your application.*  Only you can decide that.

Comment: OK.  So you've changed the code to a new version that you like better without compromising performance.  What is your specific question?

Comment: It might not be possible to do that without compromising performance.  Are you willing to sacrifice performance for better style?

Comment: To modify an immutable collection, you essentially have to copy the collection to a new collection, modifying the data en-route.  That's always going to take some time.  Some collections such as trees allow pruning (which is faster than copying the entire collection), but there's always a performance hit of some kind.

Comment: That's why developers have choices.  Sometimes you don't need mutability, so you can use an immutable collection without performance issues.  Sometimes you need high-performance and that overrides immutability considerations.

Comment: Where do `offset`, `n` and `input` come from in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use `Generic.List` solely to have a collection you can access by index. You can use built-in [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.array-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) instead.
Here's the code

```
let valuefolded =        
        [0..( (n - (offset % input.Length) - 1) / input.Length)]
        |> List.fold
            (fun acc _ -> List.append acc input)
            (input
            |> List.skip (offset % input.Length))
        |> Array.ofList
```

Also, I encourage you to check it yourself but my observation for the following parameters

```
let offset = 1
    let input = [1..10000000]
    let n = 3
```

show that it performs faster than original version.

Comment: @Giulio - You almost never want to access an immutable list by index since it's O(n) compared with O(1) for an array.